# Putting a new, updated PrestaShop site live

Tags: migration, prestashop, web-deployment, prestashop-1.7

I need some best-practice advice for how best to go-live with a new PrestaShop store.

The background: we have been working on a new store, with new core (PrestaShop version) and new design (updated theme).

Next: very soon, we need to put this store live, but we already have a live (and active) PrestaShop store.

So, what is the best approach to get this new store live?

Of concern are the changes to the current live version whilst the new one has been developed - content, orders, accounts etc which need to persist.

FYI we have full server access with cPanel, SSH etc.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is your current store built with PrestaShop?

Comment: @MahdiShad sorry yes all is PrestasShop

Comment: ok and which version (current)?

Comment: So live is 1.7.4.4 and new version 1.7.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the current live site in Maintenance for a few hours at a time when you have less visitors: use a module like [MigrationPro][1]

[1]: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/data-migration-backup/8934-migrationpro-prestashop-upgrade-and-migrate-tool.html or look for some free scripts on Prestashop forum->Free modules section (although I recommend the module above; not affiliated with them just used it several times).

Migrate the data, check if everything alright and if it is, just move elsewhere (as a backup) the files in the web directory and move there the new shop files (set the new shop on maintenance too).

Clear all caches, test it the set it online.

Comment: Thank you. By migrate the data do you mean from our new (not live) store to our live store? If so of course we need to be sure to keep the critical shop data, but update data such as module positions and configurations etc

Comment: I mean viceversa, from the live shop (which during the time you developed the new one accumulated clients, orders etc) to the new one. And you don't have to migrate the full DB just the clients, orders, carts, messages and some, possibly some module tables if you have thirdparty modules with tables which data you need to preserve.

Comment: That sounds better ! And how do we literally put the new site live ? Is it a good idea to move the site root of the domain to the new folder via cPanel ? I am wondering if file/folders ownership/permissions will be OK...

Comment: Do you know how we migrate module data/settings? I see that this is not covered by the migration module

Comment: It is now over 1 week since putting our new site live and this is the closest response to the actual method I took - I will post a response myself with my method

Comment: Somehow I missed the notification about your last comment, sorry! No use for you since you already done it but for the future readers... usually, migrating module settings is done automatically for the settings stored in the ps_configuration table and have to be done manually, for the data stored in the module table (if the module have such a table), by exporting/importing the said table.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is:

1. Putting the main site in maintenance mode
2. Moving the main site to a new test address
3. Upgrading the test site in the new address to the desired version of Prestashop
4. Getting output from the desired template (your custom theme) and importing it on the test site
5. If there is no problem, you can move the test site to the main site (files and databases) or do the same thing again on the main site.

Comment: Thanks ! I dont think this approach works for us as we have already developed a new store, with theme changes, new modules, new PrestaShop version - so I think this is the site which should be put live - just needs to be updated from prod/live

Comment: Based on my 9 years of experience developing Prestashop, this is the safest way to do this. When you export your new theme, all your new modules will be exported along with the theme.
In any case, in my opinion (based on experience), a Prestashop upgrade is much safer than transferring data. But in the end, it's your project and your choice

Comment: Thank you that is interesting to know that the modules are exported with the theme - do you talk of the Export Active Theme button in PrestaShop ? I have tried the Migration Pro module but it stops at importing clients, so your approach is of interest ... however, I am concerned that the main site could be in maintenance mode for a very long time whilst we update/replace extensions and test functionality ...

Comment: The theme's modules may be exported in a theme package, however the DB data for customers, orders and such is not; you still need to export it from the old site to  the new site. Contact the Migration Pro devs about the import getting interrupted, it may depend on your server configuration and the amount of data but as far as I know it can be done in batches too. Every day the old site is running new data is added so at some point you need to import it into the new shop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a process and create documentation.

1. Create a copy of the live shop folders and database to a new address like /test.
2. Upgrade your test shop to the new version 1.7.6.5.
3. Start moving your theme and modules from your new store to the upgraded test shop.
4. Create documentation of every change. like moving files, moving modules DB tables, and more.
5. Create a backup of your current live shop.
6. Repeat 1-3 steps and follow your documentation in your live shop.

I think you can move everything in a few hours if you have a step by step guide.

Comment: I am not clear what your solution is ... is to re-apply all changes to the live site ?

Comment: @Jono Yes, because when you install a theme or module some data will be set in DB. In step 3 you may need to install a theme and new modules and change the configurations, In Step 4 you have a copy of the live shop merged with the new shop and you can test everything like registration and placing an order process. Therefore applying all changes to the live shop will be safe and very fast.